# Different behavior running and debugging the program Java, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have this code (put aside its appropriateness for now):

```
    Class<?> cacheClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer$IntegerCache");
    Field cacheField = cacheClass.getDeclaredField("cache");
    cacheField.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(cacheField, cacheField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    Integer betterCache[] = new Integer[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < betterCache.length; i++) {
        betterCache[i] = 20;
    }
    cacheField.set(null,  betterCache);
    System.out.println(10);
    System.out.println((Integer) 10);
```

I expect the second `println` to print 20, as I replaced cached `Integers` with 20. When I debug program in Eclipse it does as I expect, it gets the value from the cache and prints 20, whereas it prints 10 in both cases when I just run it either from IDE or by invoking `java`. How can this behavior be explained?

UPD:
It works this way if compiled with 1.8 javac. It prints 10 and 20 if compiled with 1.6 version.

Comment: You are printing 10 in both cases. So why should it print 20 ?

Comment: In the second case it's an object, so it calls `Integer.valueOf` method to print it, and in that method it takes values from the cache I just substituted with an array filled with 20.

Comment: Interesting problem (though you are playing with fire).

Comment: Have you tried with maven or java -jar ? I think some IDE's cache could cause this problem.

Comment: @ahll, yes running `java -jar` (1.8) gives the same result

Comment: You may find the answer at [Change final value compiled by JIT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34897278/2796832) interesting too as you are dealing with final just like that question.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely caused by Just in Time Compiler. You should add -XX:+PrintCompilation to JVM options, it is also more visible if you iterate

```
System.out.println((Integer) 10);
```

a lot of times.
You will notice that compiling

```
java.lang.Integer::valueOf (32 bytes)
```

and

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer::arrayOffset (35 bytes)
```

affects the result.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the output of `-xx:+PrintCompilation`... I went through it but really couldn't understand much...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

**I was completely wrong**

Definitely you are playing with fire, in my point of view, this is for a race conditions (unsafe thread in java 8). If you check this:

```
    Class<?> cacheClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer$IntegerCache");
    Field cacheField = cacheClass.getDeclaredField("cache");
    cacheField.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(cacheField, cacheField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    Integer firstCache[] = (Integer[])cacheField.get(null);
    Integer betterCache[] = new Integer[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < betterCache.length; i++) {
        betterCache[i] = 20;
    }
    System.out.println(firstCache == betterCache);
    cacheField.set(null, betterCache);
    System.out.println(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        System.out.println((Integer) 10);     
    }
```

You'll see the Java burn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't understand why changing `20` (basically call to `valueOf`) to creating new value changes this behavior. It does not seem it's evaluated in compile-time (though bytecode stuff is very unclear to me), as in the bytecode for both versions there is the same statement `bipush        10` for the second `println`. Please also see update to my question

Comment: @cliffroot I don't know, but I can see differences with/without breakpoints In debug mode. I'm start to thinking in a race conditions.

Comment: Art Taylor: "_I have two new rules.
1) If your application is slow, add caching.
2) If your application is buggy, remove caching._"
https://twitter.com/reeses/status/157344234339446784

Comment: lol. You know what's funny. I tried that loop for 100. *Sometimes* it writes down 20 as first value and then all 10, sometimes it doesn't (all 10)

Comment: @cliffroot when I tried with 1000000, It show 158, WTF!

Comment: Thankfully, for me it went just 10 and then after certain moments 20